# Get a sum in a field with some specific lines of the input table by sql

Tags: sql

Table:

```
trans_id,type,cost
```

I want something like:

```
select type,sum(cost) from table group by type;
```

But I don't want all lines of the table, I just need **the line whose `trans_id` with cost of type `0`** in any line.

For example:

```
trans_id  type  cost
0         2     2
0         0     3
1         0     2
2         1     2
0         1     3
2         2     4
```

I want to get an table with:

```
trans_id  type  cost
0         2     2
0         0     3
1         0     2
0         1     3
```

(for trans_id 2, it doesn't have any type 0 line in the table, so I don't need that)then do

```
select type,sum(cost) from table group by type;
```

How do that job in sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select type,sum(cost) as Cost from TableName 
WHERE trans_id in (SELECT trans_id FROM TableName WHERE type=0)
group by type;
```

The result is:

```
TYPE    COST
0       5
1       3
2       2
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1000/5).

**For example:**

```
select * from TableName 
WHERE trans_id in (SELECT trans_id FROM TableName WHERE type=0)
```

Will give you the result:

```
TRANS_ID    TYPE    COST
0           2       2
0           0       3
1           0       2
0           1       3
```

See demo in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1000/4).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select type,sum(cost) from 
(
select trans_id,type,cost from table1
where trans_id in (0, 1)
) AS T
group by type
```